# How to get instagram media by hashtag using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, instagram

I want public media by tag name using instagram api, But i am getting blank result when i run following code.

```
$tag = 'Tag Here';
$instagram = new Instagram($instagram);
    $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($media);
```

I am using https://github.com/ianckc/CodeIgniter-Instagram-Library library

Comment: What does blank result mean? do you get a white page due to a PHP error?

Comment: just white page without any error

Comment: Enable error_reporting.

Comment: already enabled but still blank screen. In CI define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');

Comment: hey that library is really old. i haven't it used it but maybe check out this one its probably more up to date with the api. https://github.com/suhindra/CodeIgniter-Instagram-API

Comment: Is it necessary to submit app for review to access this feature? I am using testing mode